# Вывод не правильного значения

Tags: массивы, php, post, if

ИЛИ объясните как я настроил `foreach`

Если мы вводит в строку `echo "Сколько пар?<input type='text' name='collec' >` 3 то имеем три поля для выбора дат. и мы их заполняем ...но далее если мы хотим получить значение 3его элемента `echo $value[2].'<br>';` то выводит почему то просто 1
почему так?

```
    if(isset($_POST['redgr']) && $_POST['vlec'] =='On')
    {   
        $g=$_POST['group'];
        $d=$_POST['дисциплина'];
        echo "Сколько пар?<input type='text' name='collec' >
                <input type='submit' name='adcollec'>";}
     if(isset($_POST['adcollec']))
                        {   
                            $acol=$_POST['collec'];
                            echo count($acol). "ONO<br>";

                                    for($i=0;$i<$acol;$i++)
                                        {
                                            echo "<input type='date' name='cd[$i]' >";
                                            }

                            echo"<input type='submit' name='addate'>";

                            }if(isset($_POST['addate'])  or die(mysql_error()))
                            {   
                                $ma=$_POST['cd'];

                                foreach($ma as $key=>$value)    {
                                    echo $value.'<br>'; }
                                echo $value[2].'<br>';
                                                }
```

почему выводит при строке

> $value[2]."<br>"; значение 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо писать не 'echo $value[2].'<br>';'
а  надо 'echo $ma[2].'<br>';'
=3

Comment: отметьте правильным=3